# Item view add hover card

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, list-form

I've built a ticket tracker in SharePoint, but I'd like to add a hover card (ideally over a circle with an i in it) to the status field listed. So it would say something like:

1 means I got it

2 means I looked at it

...

Current formatting code below:

```
{
    "sections": [
        {
            "displayname": "Ticket Data",
            "fields": [
                "Submitted by",
                "Assigned To",
                "Due Date",
                "Title",
                "Ticket Number",
                "Please select the department(s) this request is for:",
                "Notes",
                "Please select your request type:",
                "Status"
            ]
        },
```

Comment: Are you trying to add custom `i` and hover card on list form or in list view?

Comment: List form please.

Comment: Hi @Phil, does my below answer help you in any way? Let me know if you need any further help on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, thses types of customizations are *not supported* using JSON formatting capabilities. You cannot create custom buttons / elements or hover cards in body section of list forms.

> Unlike the header and the footer, body configuration **only allows defining one or more sections** and adding one or more columns into each of those sections.

Body configuration does not support advance JSON customizations like header/footer (or column/view formatting in list views).

**Source**: [Configure custom body with one or more sections](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration#configure-custom-body-with-one-or-more-sections)

---

You have below options:

1. You can use **Description** available in column settings to show such text near form fields.
2. You can use header layout form formatting to show custom message at the top of list form
3. Or customize list forms using Power Apps to buttons and custom tootip